# Git submodule update from CI with access token

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, access-token, git-submodules

I am trying to update git submodules from .gitlab-ci.yml.
As mentioned on Gitlab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html#:%7E:text=clone%20it%20locally.-,Using%20relative%20URLs,-If%20you%20use), If the submodules are on the same git server, I should use relative path; Using absolute path (HTTPS) doesn't work.

Submodule1 is in project1 which doesn't require access token; whereas submodule2 is in project2 (my project where CI yml file exists), which requires use of access token. Therefore, below code works for submodule1 update but fails for submodule2.

```
[submodule "Project2/submodule1"]
    path = Project2/submodule1
    url = ../../Project1/sample/submodule1.git
[submodule "Project2/submodule2"]
    path = Project2/submodule2
    url = ../Project2/submodule2.git
```

**Error**:
Cloning into '/Project2/submodule2'...
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
fatal: repository 'https://git.com/Project2/submodule2.git/' not found
fatal: clone of 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@git.com/Project2/submodule2.git' into submodule path '/Project2/submodule2' failed
Failed to clone 'Project2/submodule2'. Retry scheduled

**Tried below options**:

1. Use access token

```
url = https://gitlab-ci-token:${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}@git.com/Project2/submodule2.git
```

as url in .gitmodules, it gives `could not read Username for 'https://git.com': No such device or address` error. I can clone to above url though, so its a valid url.

2. Use git config in yml file as follows:

```
- git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN}@git.com".insteadOf "https://git.com"
- git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
```

Nothing works. Any idea how to update submodule in CI with personal access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

1. Add the path of the parent project (where .gitmodules/.gitlab-ci.yml file is) to the Settings -> CI/CD → Token Access section of the submodule.
2. To update the Git submodule from .gitlab-ci.yml file, use the command `git submodule update --remote --init`.